# problem in TextView in android

Tags: android, textview

hi all i m making a sample app. for update List.
i have a list class and its xml is like.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/more" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Click to view more..." 
android:textStyle="normal|bold" android:textColor="#FF8000"      android:textSize="10dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

now i have set TouchListener of text View and added the following code in it

```
    @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.more:
        //update List Method Call..
        more.setText("Click to view More..");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

You see on the 3rd line of switch statement i have added

```
 more.setText("Click to view More..");
```

line but when my list is updated . The text View is no longer shows in the bottom . 
Please Guide my why this is happening to me and whats the solution??

Comment: at begin your textview was display at bottom of the list..?

Comment: yes at begining it displayes . but when it list got update.it disappears

Comment: and at begining listview have any data.?

Comment: Yes at beg  it has 5 list Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code..
footer_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="7dip"
android:paddingBottom="7dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView 
    android:text="footer_text_1" 
    android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="14dip" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
</TextView> 

 </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

and use the following in code:

```
public class listactivty extends ListActivity{
 private Context context = null;
 private ListView list = null;  

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
//code to set adapter to populate list

 View footerView = 
      ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
    list.addFooterView(footerView);
}
```

use seperate XML file for ListView..

Thanks
Shahjahan Ahmad

Answer (score 2):

you can use list footer in that case.

add this code in ur java file. and add footer dynamically in your list.

```
TextView more = new TextView(this);
more.setText("Click to view more...");
more.setClickable(true);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, Height);
more.setLayoutParams(params);

more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //update List Method Call..
          more.setText("Click to view More..");
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
listView.addFooterView(more);
```

this can help you.

Comment: set clickable to text view - more and set alignment.

Comment: how can i set Id to TextView- more so that i could get that into onClickListener

Comment: no need to set id. you have textView instance in more so you can set onClickListemer on that and remove textView from xml.

Answer (score 1):

try `android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/more"` in the `ListView`. Now even if ur `ListView` grows it wont hide the `TextView`.

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeList"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinearBottom3">
    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/chathlist"
     />
</RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearBottom3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"><!--Make it as center-->
  <TextView  android:id="@+id/more" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Click to view more..." android:textStyle="normal|bold" android:textSize="10dip"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
  </ReletiveLayout>
```

Comment: you mean and i need to implement RelativeLayout instaead of Linear one??

Comment: Yeah u need the relativelayout.. This is working fine for me.

Comment: Else give it as a try. Make these two in separate layout and try using `ListView` layout height as `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/more"></ListView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/more" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Click to view more..." 
android:textStyle="normal|bold" android:textColor="#FF8000"      android:textSize="10dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oops... Not succedded Yet with this one as well. it displayes me the View First but when i click on it it is blank

Comment: The code above stated is the whole code. and the part which has //update List Method Call..
will be replaced with my Method of updating List View Items

Comment: check had u used more.setVisibility(View.GONE or INVISIBLE) in any where..?

Answer (score 1):

try this..
footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dip" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Click to view More.." android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/more"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

in class file

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout footer = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.footer, null);
TextView more= (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.more);



 more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //List Update Code
            }
        });
```